# Can not evaluate UIID

Tags: user-interface, codenameone

[image: Screenshot of a CocenameOne application]

Who can tell me what the UIID of this element is?

Comment: What are you trying to do? Please explain your problem more clearly.

Answer (score 0):

The UIID is `Command` the surrounding border is `CommandList`.

Comment: Just trying to change the background color.